# Add A repeator field using flexform in custom extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I want a common field "Images" containing two subfields top image and bottom image. The common field "Images" should be repeatable field that means able to add multiple times. I am attaching the demo below. Can anyone help please?
[image]

This is my flexform code. There is two fields of image top image and bottom image. i want to make these two to my functionality.

```html
<T3DataStructure>
  <sheets>
    <sDEF>
      <ROOT>
        <TCEforms>
          <sheetTitle>Settings</sheetTitle>
        </TCEforms>
        <type>array</type>
        <el>
          <settings.gallerytype>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Gallery Type</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <config>
                <type>select</type>
                <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
                <items type="array">
                  <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">-Select-</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Simple Gallery</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">0</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="2" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Parallax</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">1</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="3" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Grid Gallery</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">2</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="4" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Sliders</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">3</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="5" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Portfolio</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">4</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="6" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Filter Gallery</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">5</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                </items>
                <minitems>1</minitems>
                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                <size>1</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.gallerytype>
          <settings.gridsubstyle>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Select the style for gallery type</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <displayCond>FIELD:settings.gallerytype:=:2</displayCond>
              <config>
                <type>select</type>
                <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
                <items type="array">
                  <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">One column Image display</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">6</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="2" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Two column Image display</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">7</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="3" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Three column Image display</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">8</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="4" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Four column Image display</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">9</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                </items>
                <minitems>1</minitems>
                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                <size>1</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.gridsubstyle>

          <settings.slidersubstyle>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Select the style for gallery type</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <displayCond>FIELD:settings.gallerytype:=:3</displayCond>
              <config>
                <type>select</type>
                <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
                <items type="array">
                  <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">-Select-</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Banner Slider</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">10</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="2" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Treadmill</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">11</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                </items>
                <minitems>1</minitems>
                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                <size>1</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.slidersubstyle>


          <settings.filtersubstyle>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Select the style for gallery type</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <displayCond>FIELD:settings.gallerytype:=:5</displayCond>
              <config>
                <type>select</type>
                <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
                <items type="array">
                  <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">-Select-</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Gallery with Filter</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">12</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="2" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">Standard Gallery with Filter</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">13</numIndex>
                  </numIndex>
                </items>
                <minitems>1</minitems>
                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                <size>1</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.filtersubstyle>

          <settings.gallerytitle>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Gallery Title</label>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>200</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.gallerytitle>
          <galleryimage>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Images</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <displayCond>
                <OR>
                  <numIndex index="1">FIELD:settings.gallerytype:=:0</numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="2">FIELD:settings.gallerytype:=:1</numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="3">FIELD:settings.gallerytype:=:4</numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="4">FIELD:settings.gridsubstyle:=:6</numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="5">FIELD:settings.gridsubstyle:=:7</numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="6">FIELD:settings.gridsubstyle:=:8</numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="7">FIELD:settings.gridsubstyle:=:9</numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="8">FIELD:settings.slidersubstyle:=:10</numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="9">FIELD:settings.filtersubstyle:=:12</numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="10">FIELD:settings.filtersubstyle:=:13</numIndex>
                </OR>
              </displayCond>
              <config>
                <type>inline</type>
                <maxitems>2000</maxitems>
                <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
                <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
                <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
                <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
                <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
                <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
                <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                  <config>
                    <appearance>
                      <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                      <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,jpeg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                    </appearance>
                  </config>
                </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                <foreign_types type="array">
                  <numIndex index="0">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="2">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                  </numIndex>
                </foreign_types>
                <foreign_match_fields>
                  <fieldname>Galleryimage</fieldname>
                  <!-- CAUTION!! Replace "fal" with the variable name of this field! -->
                </foreign_match_fields>
                <appearance type="array">
                  <newRecordLinkAddTitle>1</newRecordLinkAddTitle>
                  <useSortable>1</useSortable>
                  <headerThumbnail>
                    <field>uid_local</field>
                    <height>64</height>
                    <width>64</width>
                  </headerThumbnail>
                  <enabledControls>
                    <info>1</info>
                    <new>0</new>
                    <dragdrop>0</dragdrop>
                    <sort>1</sort>
                    <hide>1</hide>
                    <delete>1</delete>
                    <localize>1</localize>
                  </enabledControls>
                  <createNewRelationLinkTitle>LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference</createNewRelationLinkTitle>
                </appearance>
                <behaviour>
                  <localizationMode>select</localizationMode>
                  <localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>1</localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>
                </behaviour>
                <overrideChildTca>
                  <columns type="array">
                    <uid_local type="array">
                      <config type="array">
                        <appearance type="array">
                          <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                          <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,jpeg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                        </appearance>
                      </config>
                    </uid_local>
                  </columns>
                  <types type="array">
                    <numIndex index="2">
                      <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                  </types>
                </overrideChildTca>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </galleryimage>
          <topimage>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Top Image</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <displayCond>
                <OR>
                  <numIndex index="1">FIELD:settings.slidersubstyle:=:11</numIndex>
                </OR>
              </displayCond>
              <config>
                <type>inline</type>
                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
                <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
                <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
                <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
                <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
                <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
                <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                  <config>
                    <appearance>
                      <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                      <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,jpeg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                    </appearance>
                  </config>
                </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                <foreign_types type="array">
                  <numIndex index="0">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="2">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                  </numIndex>
                </foreign_types>
                <foreign_match_fields>
                  <fieldname>Topimage</fieldname>
                  <!-- CAUTION!! Replace "fal" with the variable name of this field! -->
                </foreign_match_fields>
                <appearance type="array">
                  <newRecordLinkAddTitle>1</newRecordLinkAddTitle>
                  <useSortable>1</useSortable>
                  <headerThumbnail>
                    <field>uid_local</field>
                    <height>64</height>
                    <width>64</width>
                  </headerThumbnail>
                  <enabledControls>
                    <info>1</info>
                    <new>0</new>
                    <dragdrop>0</dragdrop>
                    <sort>1</sort>
                    <hide>1</hide>
                    <delete>1</delete>
                    <localize>1</localize>
                  </enabledControls>
                  <createNewRelationLinkTitle>LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference</createNewRelationLinkTitle>
                </appearance>
                <behaviour>
                  <localizationMode>select</localizationMode>
                  <localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>1</localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>
                </behaviour>
                <overrideChildTca>
                  <columns type="array">
                    <uid_local type="array">
                      <config type="array">
                        <appearance type="array">
                          <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                          <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,jpeg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                        </appearance>
                      </config>
                    </uid_local>
                  </columns>
                  <types type="array">
                    <numIndex index="2">
                      <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                  </types>
                </overrideChildTca>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </topimage>

          <bottomimage>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Bottom Image</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <displayCond>
                <OR>
                  <numIndex index="1">FIELD:settings.slidersubstyle:=:11</numIndex>
                </OR>
              </displayCond>
              <config>
                <type>inline</type>
                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
                <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
                <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
                <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
                <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
                <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
                <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                  <config>
                    <appearance>
                      <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                      <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,jpeg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                    </appearance>
                  </config>
                </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                <foreign_types type="array">
                  <numIndex index="0">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="2">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                  </numIndex>
                </foreign_types>
                <foreign_match_fields>
                  <fieldname>Bottomimage</fieldname>
                  <!-- CAUTION!! Replace "fal" with the variable name of this field! -->
                </foreign_match_fields>
                <appearance type="array">
                  <newRecordLinkAddTitle>1</newRecordLinkAddTitle>
                  <useSortable>1</useSortable>
                  <headerThumbnail>
                    <field>uid_local</field>
                    <height>64</height>
                    <width>64</width>
                  </headerThumbnail>
                  <enabledControls>
                    <info>1</info>
                    <new>0</new>
                    <dragdrop>0</dragdrop>
                    <sort>1</sort>
                    <hide>1</hide>
                    <delete>1</delete>
                    <localize>1</localize>
                  </enabledControls>
                  <createNewRelationLinkTitle>LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference</createNewRelationLinkTitle>
                </appearance>
                <behaviour>
                  <localizationMode>select</localizationMode>
                  <localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>1</localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>
                </behaviour>
                <overrideChildTca>
                  <columns type="array">
                    <uid_local type="array">
                      <config type="array">
                        <appearance type="array">
                          <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                          <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,jpeg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                        </appearance>
                      </config>
                    </uid_local>
                  </columns>
                  <types type="array">
                    <numIndex index="2">
                      <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                  </types>
                </overrideChildTca>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </bottomimage>
          <settings.treadmill>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Add media</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <displayCond>
                <OR>
                  <numIndex index="1">FIELD:settings.slidersubstyle:=:11</numIndex>
                </OR>
              </displayCond>
              <config>
                <type>inline</type>
                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
                <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
                <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
                <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
                <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
                <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
                <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                  <config>
                    <appearance>
                      <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                      <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,jpeg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                    </appearance>
                  </config>
                </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                <foreign_types type="array">
                  <numIndex index="0">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                  </numIndex>
                  <numIndex index="2">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                  </numIndex>
                </foreign_types>
                <foreign_match_fields>
                  <fieldname>Bottomimage</fieldname>
                  <!-- CAUTION!! Replace "fal" with the variable name of this field! -->
                </foreign_match_fields>
                <appearance type="array">
                  <newRecordLinkAddTitle>1</newRecordLinkAddTitle>
                  <useSortable>1</useSortable>
                  <headerThumbnail>
                    <field>uid_local</field>
                    <height>64</height>
                    <width>64</width>
                  </headerThumbnail>
                  <enabledControls>
                    <info>1</info>
                    <new>0</new>
                    <dragdrop>0</dragdrop>
                    <sort>1</sort>
                    <hide>1</hide>
                    <delete>1</delete>
                    <localize>1</localize>
                  </enabledControls>
                  <createNewRelationLinkTitle>LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference</createNewRelationLinkTitle>
                </appearance>
                <behaviour>
                  <localizationMode>select</localizationMode>
                  <localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>1</localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>
                </behaviour>
                <overrideChildTca>
                  <columns type="array">
                    <uid_local type="array">
                      <config type="array">
                        <appearance type="array">
                          <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                          <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,jpeg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                        </appearance>
                      </config>
                    </uid_local>
                  </columns>
                  <types type="array">
                    <numIndex index="2">
                      <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                  </types>
                </overrideChildTca>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.treadmill>
          <settings.enablefilter>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>Enable Filter</label>
              <config>
                <type>check</type>
                <maxitems>2</maxitems>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.enablefilter>
        </el>
      </ROOT>
    </sDEF>
  </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional record-type "image" (including TCA, SQL-table and so on), having the two required fields "Top image" and "Bottom image". Then configure an [IRRE/inline-type](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline/Index.html) field in the parent record.

Comment: Can you give an example code? because i am new in typo3.

Comment: I have added the flexform code in my question...can you please check? Please help.